# How can I have a universal ON/OFF switch on my website which anyone can click on or off?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, switch-statement

I have a website which needs to have a single button which anyone who visits the site can turn on or off. I'm using google appengine. The variable is unable to change from "off" to  "on"... I'm confused as to where my error is. I'm still new to this stuff.

I'm not sure how to have this universal variable.. I started by using NDB to store a variable, but I'm unable to changed the variable from "off" to "on". I'm hoping to get an outside opinion on how this might be easier to work.

This is what I have so far as my structure for the variable.

```
class UpdatedThing(ndb.Model):
    OnOff = ndb.StringProperty(default='off')

def switch(s):
    onoff = UpdatedThing()
    if s == "on":
        onoff.OnOff = "off"
    else:
        onoff.OnOff = "on"
    onoff.put()
    print s
```

The "s" variable is the current value for the on/off button, which is navigated from here.

```
class Switch(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
      s = models.UpdatedThing().OnOff 
      print s
      models.switch(s)
      self.redirect('/')
```

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by "_unable to changed_"? getting error, not saved, or what?

Comment: Its not getting saved my change. The variable OnOff is always "off", even when I click to change it to "on". I can't seem to find the error myself.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call UpdateThing() you are creating a new instance of UpdateThing model , this means you will have a new one created.  If you have a single entity or any number of entities you want updated you need to retrieve (get()) the entity and then update it and then save those changes to the datastore (save())

Also from a design point of view the `switch` function should really be a method of the Thing object, also I think your model name should be Thing rather than UpdateThing.  UpdateThing isn't a noun.  It implies doing something but your working with an entity.

Answer (score 0):

Tim is exactly right: you need a single instance of the entity, not a new one on every setting and query. Ignoring his reasonable style criticism, and sticking to your chosen naming and structure, something like:

Assuming this part is in models.py:

```
import ndb

class UpdatedThing(ndb.Model):
    OnOff = ndb.StringProperty(default='off')

def get_or_make_thing():
    # get the existing entity
    onoff = UpdatedThing.query().get()
    # if none existed, make one
    if onoff is None: onoff = UpdatedThing()
    return onoff

def switch(s):
    onoff = get_or_make_thing()
    if s == "on":
        onoff.OnOff = "off"
    else:
        onoff.OnOff = "on"
    onoff.put()
    # why print? if you need to see it, use logging! print s
```

and this part is in someother py file:

```
import models
import webapp2

class Switch(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
      s = models.get_or_make_thing().OnOff 
      # again, print in app enging makes no sense: print s
      models.switch(s)
      self.redirect('/')
```

Those `print`s make no sense in App Engine, so I've commented them out -- if you need to keep a log of events, import `logging` and call `logging.info`.

Comment: What is the downside of printing? I've used it on occasion and it seemed to work fine. Or maybe there are advantages to logging?

Comment: `print` sends to `sys.stdout`, which on an App Engine server (like on most other web servers) is not configured to go anywhere in particular. logging calls (typically `logging.info` for typical informational messages, though just `logging.debug` for messages that are of debugging significance only) records the messages to locations where they can be examined (via the developers console in production; in a local dev_appserver, to a file you can e.g keep a `tail -f` on in its own terminal window if you need real-time display) together with important admin messages from the system.

Comment: You will also find print can cause odd things with the output stream of your handler, especially if you print before request.write() calls.